# how to prevent C# from forcing excel file to open as read only?

Tags: c#, excel

When I open an Excel(.xlsm) through either System.Diagnostics.Process.Start or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, the file is forced to start in read only mode, How to prevent this and start in the normal way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't the problem `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`. Because Your file is read-only already.

Try to force attribute of the file before opening it.

The is a lot of examples of codes to do that

I.E

```
File.SetAttributes(fileExcelPath, attr & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: For reference, [`File.SetAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_SetAttributes_System_String_System_IO_FileAttributes_) and [field types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=netframework-4.7.2)